# Group cannot be added anymore as author of SharePoint Online news

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-news

When creating a news in SharePoint Online, we were able to add a Group as the author, e.g. Corporate Communication, until the beginning of December. For about two weeks now this is not possible anymore. Entering a group in the author field just below the news page's title does work. However, it would not save or publish the news page. This only works with persons added as author.

Any ideas, why this has changed and how to solve it?
[image]